# react, angular 2 and meteor (blaze) browsers compatibility

Tags: reactjs, cross-browser, angular, meteor-blaze

Sorry for the question, but I'm not able to find the browsers support of these 3 frameworks. I know that they support IE8 or more, but there are not any list from which version of Chrome, Firefox or Opera do they start supporting... I also know that any version which supports ECMA5 methods should work, but not sure if that's the only tip.

Any util link?

This a very complete in Wikipedia, but not mention to the 3 I need. I will update the Wikipedia page with the information, but need to be sure.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

That's a question you can't really answer as the view model has nothing to do with browser compatibility besides ecma version, but even there are transpilers which flatten this poblem.

They are all "cross-browser" as long as you use cross-browser html and css.

Comment: I'm not talking about transpilers. Have I to suppose that every chrome/firefox/opera browser which support ECMA5, must support React JS? I'm not sure if that's the only point to consider...

Comment: It actually is the only thing you have to consider. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/ so for example ie 8 won't work with any modern frontend freamwork. You may even get this working, but then u have some polyfill workarounds which are freamwork specific. The thing where browser compatibiliy comes in place is when looking for packages (e.g. https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) - it's react, so everything should work in firefox, but you probably face some css problems and stuff like that on ff you don't see on chrome because their are fine granular changes between them.

Comment: you may have cross-browser html and css, but still have incompatible javascript that wont run on some browsers